# Rails - Form not passing validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**I have these validation rules:**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

end
```

**Here is debug(params)**

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: rqWNFu2/jeoZfTTZD5N6M080UcazPZR2hl0ON92sxnA=
employee: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  name: xxx
  email: yyyy@zzzz.com
  password: '123456'
  password_confirmation: '123456'
commit: Create Employee
action: create
controller: employees
```

But the validation still fails saying:

```
Email can't be blank
Email is invalid
Password can't be blank
Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

**edit: controller code**

```
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.save
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Anyone can explain to me what i am doing wrong? The params seems to be fine and filled correctly but i still can't pass the validation

Comment: Show your controller code.

Comment: Have you declared employee_params correctly? Please show us that as well?

Comment: +1 for employee_params

Comment: +1 for show us the code for the "employee_params" method in the controller

Comment: @Prajjwal , Please post your comment as an answer so i'll be able to mark it as correct. What i can't understand is why employee_params isn't automatically generated with 'rails g scaffold'? Can it be related to the fact that i generated :email, :password and :password_confirmation using migration and not when i generated the scaffold?

Comment: @user3459815 Done. Probably, if it didn't know what your model was supposed to look like during scaffold generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by incorrect use of [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). Declaring employee_params the following way should fix it:

```
private
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With Rails4 **`Strong Parameters`** concept, you must **`permit`** the parameters that you would like to `insert(create action)/update(update action)` in database explicitly else they won't pass through.

Permit `email` and `password` in `employee_params` method.

`employee_params` should look as below:

```
  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name)
  end
```